# Drop down menu: bad position

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

so I'm making drop down menu and I've made when you hover on a text you see other options, but it's not in the correct position.

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/eyj5fghk/

```css
#wrap {
 margin:10px auto 10px auto;
 height:auto;
 width:1000px;
}

header {
 background-color:#fff;
 height:111px;
 width:100%;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 border-bottom:solid 1px #e7e7e7;
}

nav ul {
 margin-top:43px;
 padding:0;
 list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display:block;
}

nav ul li {
 display:inline;
 font-family:Courier new;
 color:#000;
 
    list-style: none; 
}

nav ul ul {
 display:none;
 position: absolute;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:list-item;
}


nav ul li a {
 margin-right:57px;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#000;
 
}

nav ul li a:hover {
 border-bottom:solid 1px #000;
 padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="wrap">
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="javascript:;">one</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:;">two</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:;">three</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:;">four</a></li>
     <li>
      four with children &#9662;
      <ul>
       <li>five . 1</li>
       <li>five . 2</li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
```

Comment: What does "not in right position" mean?

Comment: it has to be below word "kita", but now it's below header

Comment: Tweak a bit your css, look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eyj5fghk/1/)... than you can delete your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `position:relative` from the parent `ul` and place it on the `li`

Then change the `display` property on the `li` to `inline-block`.

```css
#wrap {
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 1000px;
}
header {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 111px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #e7e7e7;
}
nav ul {
  margin-top: 43px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Courier new;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: list-item;
}
nav ul li a {
  margin-right: 57px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="wrap">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">pradinis</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="istorija.html">istorija</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="laimejimai.html">laimėjimai</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="sportininkai.html">sportininkai</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            kita &#9662;
            <ul>
              <li>nuorodos</li>
              <li>galerija</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nav {

    width: 960px;

}

nav ul {

    padding: 0px;

    margin: 0px;

}

nav ul:after {

    clear: both;

    content: " ";

    display: block;

    font-size: 0;

    height: 0;

    visibility: hidden;

}

    nav ul,nav ul li{

    background-color: #FAFAFA;

}

    nav ul li {

    list-style: none;

    float:left;

}

nav ul li a {

    text-decoration: none;

    display: block;

    color: #333;

    padding: 14px 34px 14px 34px;

}

nav ul li:hover > ul {

    visibility: visible;

}

nav ul li ul{

    display: inline;

    visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;

    padding:0px;

}

nav ul li ul li{

    float: none;

}

nav ul li ul li a:hover{

    color: #333;

}
```

```
<div id="wrap">

  <nav>

    <ul>

      <li><a href="index.html">pradinis</a></li>

      <li><a href="istorija.html">istorija</a></li>

      <li><a href="laimejimai.html">laimėjimai</a></li>

      <li><a href="sportininkai.html">sportininkai</a></li>

      <li>

        <li class = "dropMenue">

            <a href="#">kita &#9662;</a>

            <ul>

              <li><a href="#">nuorodos</a></li>

              <li><a href="#">galerija</a></li>

           </ul>        

        </li>

    </ul>

  </nav>

</div>
```